# Парсинг хэша регулярным выражением

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Здравствуйте уважаемые,
У меня такая проблема, я только начал работать с PHP и тут же проблема, не могу спарсить хэш

```
"activity":{"hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"}
```

Я новичок, так что не ругайте и гуглом не грозите, я в нем ни чего мне понятного не нашел...
Буду очень признателен

Вот часть кода

```
$str='{"user":{"id":11111111},"friends":{"count":0},"messages":{"count":0},"events":{"count":0},"groups":{"count":0},"photos":{"count":0},"videos":{"count":0},"notes":{"count":0},"gifts":{"count":0},"lang":{"id":"0","p_id":0},"activity":{"hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"}}';
preg_match_all('|"hash":(.*)"}', $str, $hash); 
print_r $hash;
```

Но почему то у меня на локхосте не
 пашет

Comment: Это - JSON. Зачем парсить? Чем не устраивает [json_decode()][1]?

  [1]: http://ua.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$hash = array();
$str='{"user":{"id":1111111},"friends":{"count":0},"messages":{"count":0},"events":{"count":0},"groups":{"count":0},"photos":{"count":0},"videos":{"count":0},"notes":{"count":0},"gifts":{"count":0},"lang":{"id":"0","p_id":0},"activity":{"hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"}}';
preg_match_all('/"hash":"([^"]+)"/', $str, $hash);
print_r($hash);
```

Comment: У меня не работало без определения массива `$hash`. И еще, `print_r` - функция, а не языковая конструкция, как `echo`, поэтому скобки обязательны.

Comment: @Rimon_Victor , а еще открою вам секрет - это JSON ))

    $arr = json_decode($str, 1);
    echo $arr['hash'];

Comment: А можете ещё подсказать как к примеру
в
friends":{"count":0}
Число 0 
отпарсить
Буду очень при очень благодарен

Comment: @Rimon_Victor, полбзуйтесь `json_decode`(коммент выше), он перегоняет всю `$str` в массив.

Если оч хочется регулярками - вот она:

    '/"friends":{"count":(\d+)/'

Answer (score 0):

Регулярным выражением нужно это делать, например:

```
preg_match_all('|"hash":(.*)"}', $str, $hash);
print_r $hash;
```

Где $str - это контент который парсится, а в массив $hash сохраняются результаты работы регулярного выражения.

Comment: Что то не получается...
Вот полный код
    $str='{"user":{"id":1111111},"friends":{"count":0},"messages":{"count":0},"events":{"count":0},"groups":{"count":0},"photos":{"count":0},"videos":{"count":0},"notes":{"count":0},"gifts":{"count":0},"lang":{"id":"0","p_id":0},"activity":{"hash":"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"}}';
preg_match_all('|"hash":(.*)"}', $str, $hash);
print_r $hash;

Comment: @Зоркий, регулярка-то кривая) Предложу: `'/"hash":"([^"]+)"/'`

Comment: С Вашей почему то тоже не хочет работать...

Comment: Всё разобрал) Спасибо Вам огромное) Вы очень меня выручили)

Comment: @Sh4dow на самом деле суть отражает, остальное доводка :) А если бы кто то полностью код отдаваем вконтактом выложил то и её бы не было :)